# multiple views and changing url

Tags: angularjs

In my use-case there are three, for lack of a better word, "views". The content displayed in the third view depends on the selections made in the second and first view. Similarly, the subtopics displayed in the second view depend on the selection made in the first view.

```
Select Topic | Select Subtopic | Display Content
------------------------------------------------------
Vegetables   | Apple           | The peach is a tasty
FRUITS*      | Banana          | fruit that has a nice
Meats        | PEACH*          | color, etc.
Fish         |                 |
```

Currently, when the user selects a topic, I get and display the list of subtopics. Once the user selects a subtopic, I then get and display the content. So far, so well.

Only problem, I also want the user to be able to access this by navigating to a url of the form:

```
example.com/index.html#/topic/subtopic
```

I have it working such that navigating to the url causes all the right content to be loaded. That is not the problem.

My problem is that I want to change the url, if a user selects a new topic or subtopic. But without causing a page-reload (which appears to be what happens if I use `location.path`. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using any routing functionality?

Comment: I tried using one ui-router state with multiple views. But when I tried to get it to reload just one view, it always reloaded the whole state. So I stopped using that, and now its all in one state.

Comment: Why use `location.path` ? Do you mean `$location.path()` ?

Comment: @Ben: Did you take a look at my answer below ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use window's `location.path`, but Angular's routing (either via `$location.path()` or implicitely changing the #hash).

With views like these:

```
<!-- Categories -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/categories.tmpl.html">
    <h3>Select a food category:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
            <a ng-href="#/{{category.path}}">{{category.label}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>

<!-- Fruits -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/fruits.tmpl.html">
    <h3>Select a fruit:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
            <a ng-href="#/fruits/{{fruit.path}}">{{fruit.label}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a ng-href="#/{{back}}">Back</a>
</script>

<!-- Meats --->
...

<!-- Vegetables -->
...

<!-- Description -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/description.tmpl.html">
    <h3>{{item}}</h3>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
    <a ng-href="#/{{back}}">Back</a>
</script>
```

appropriate controllers and services and a configuration like this:

```
function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/categories.tmpl.html',
            controller:  'categoriesCtrl'
        }).
        when('/fruits/:fruit?', {
            templateUrl: function (params) {
                return params.fruit ?
                        'partials/description.tmpl.html' : 
                        'partials/fruits.tmpl.html';
            },
            controller:  'fruitsCtrl'
        }).
        when('/meats/:meat?', {...}).
        when('/vegetables/:vegetable?', {...}).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}
```

you can achieve what you want !

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/n95ty/)**.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve exactly that is with ui-router, as far as I know.

With ngrouter, you have to change your params for query string parameters, so it would be like:

```
example.com/index.html#/myRoute?topic=topic&subtopic=subtopic
```

And then in your routes config:

```
when('/myRoute', { templateUrl: ..., reloadOnSearch: false })
```

Then you would listen for changes on the route ($routeChangeSuccess) on the controller and get the query string from there.